# what exactly is happening here in the 4th line?

Tags: jquery

I am editing my question as suggested in the comments to demonstrate a better overview on what make me confuse about the `.on` callback function in the following line:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.nav').on('click', 'li > a', function(){
    var $li = $(this).parent();
    $li.siblings().not($li.addClass('active')).removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

What is really happening in the line

```
$li.siblings().not($li.addClass('active')).removeClass('active');
```

I mean, Is it adding and removing active class base on their current state with `not($li.addClass('active'))` or it's just wrong syntax to achieve this goal.

Comment: `.not($li.addClass('active'))` doesn't really make any sense, tbh. The `.not` is evaluating the result of the `addClass` operation. So the class is added, but then that function doesn't have a documented return value so it's not clear what it would do in that scenario. Nothing useful, certainly - `.not()` expects a selector of set of elements as input, and addClass certainly doesn't return that. So it won't reduce the set of elements selected by "siblings()" to anything less that it was before.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$li.siblings().not('.active').removeClass('active');` ? which would be pointless... I think that this should be `$li.siblings('.active').removeClass('active');`

Currently you end up selecting all the siblings of your clicked 'li' and removing their `active` class

Comment: @AntoineGuillien Nevermind you edited. The original line in the OP doesn't make sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added your code and explained `hover` example.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('.nav').on('click', 'li > a', function(){
    var $li = $(this).parent();
    $li.siblings().not($li.addClass('active')).removeClass('active');
  });
  
  $('.nav').on('mouseover', 'li > a', function(){
    var $li = $(this).parent(); // get parent of hovered <a> (<li>)
    $siblings = $li.siblings(); // get all siblings of <li> containing the hovered <a>
    $li.addClass('hover'); // add 'active' to <li> containing hovered <a>
    $siblings_except_clicked = $siblings.not($li); // get all siblings NOT <li> containing hovered a
    $siblings.removeClass('hover'); // remove 'active' class from every <li> except the one with hovered <a>
  });
  
  
});
```

```css
ul.nav {
  margin: 0px pading: 0px;
}

ul.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid transparent;
}

ul.nav li.active {
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

ul.nav li.hover {
  border-top: 3px solid grey;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='nav'>
  <li class='active hover'><a href='#'>Entry A</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Entry B</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Entry C</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$li.addClass('active')
```

This returns `$li`, just in case you wanted to chain multiple functions together.

So

```
$li.siblings().not($li.addClass('active')).removeClass('active');
```

is the same as:

```
$li.addClass('active');
$li.siblings().not($li).removeClass('active');
```

Which means all the siblings of `$li`, which are not the `$li` itself.
Which is silly because it was never its own sibling to begin with.

So let's simplify it to:

```
$li.addClass('active');
$li.siblings().removeClass('active');
```

Which says, add the `active` class to the `li` which had been clicked on and remove the class from the other `li`s.

Comment: Actually, none of the lines that you recommend doesn't work like the original, what happening in the code is it add some border to a menu item that clicked and removes active class from other items of the menu. it does the job but I can't figure out how exactly.

Comment: You asked a question about the `not()` function, but now you are talking about borders.  Could you edit your question to clarify what you are asking?  Are you asking what every line of code does or only the `not()` function()?

Comment: I edit my question to clarify what was confused my about the code. @buh-buh